# replace nginx listen ports using sed

Tags: nginx, sed

file name is nginx.conf

how can i replace nginx all listen ports using sed

```
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:30m rate=20r/s;
server {
    listen 80;listen 8080;listen 443 ssl;ssl_certificate server.crt;ssl_certificate_key server.key; ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

i want replace this part:

```
listen 80;listen 8080;listen 443 ssl;
```

with new value, the new value is input by user

example - user can input this:

```
listen 8181;listen 8083 ssl;
```

or

```
listen 80;listen 8080;listen 8181;listen 9090;listen 443 ssl;
```

Note: user is free to use any values.

currently i use this command, but replaces only one value:

```
sed -i '0,/listen [0-9]*;/s//listen $NEW_PORT;/' nginx.conf
```

any help is  appreciated

thanks

Comment: Your examples don't seem to add up — either the user has to input the whole `listen` set of strings as nginx code, or, given your explicit example, only a single port can be used.  This problem would be better solved by using some sort of a template file, where you'll replace some special magic string like `%LISTEN%` with whatever needs to be used by any given user.

Comment: i cannot use template, users have different config files. with custom settings. so we need to replace and not using template

Answer (score 1):

try this work for me

```
sed  -i 's/listen 80;listen 8080;listen 443 ssl;/listen 80;listen 8080;listen 8181;listen 9090;listen 443 ssl;/g' nginx.conf
```

Comment: this way you use , we must know old values, suppose these are unknown: listen 80;listen 8080;listen 443 ssl;
we must replace freely

Answer (score -1):

i did it like this and works fine:

```
sed -i 's/listen.*ssl; *ssl_certificate/listen 80;listen 6666;listen 8888;listen 443 ssl;ssl_certificate/' nginx.conf
```

i replaced all strings between: `listen.*ssl; *ssl_certificate`

i added * between `ssl; *ssl_certificate` to ignore spaces if present